# optional dictionary items in dict creation

Tags: python, dictionary, key, conditional-statements, key-value

I have a function returning a dictionary:

```
 def to_dict(self):
     return dict({'identification': self.identifier,
                  'information': self.information,
                  'nodes': {e.position: e.to_dict for e in self.children}
                  })
```

Is there a way to optionally add each k/v? This does not work e.g:

```
def to_dict(self):
         return dict({'identification': self.identifier,
                      'information': self.information,
                      'nodes': {e.position: e.to_dict for e in self.children} if self.children
                      })
```

Is there a way to add in optional parts of dict creation without having to build a separate dictionary for each variation; is there a better way to do this even ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by 'optionally'? Depending on which condition?

Comment: Note that it is enough to use `{'key': 'value', ...}` to define a dictionary. You do not need to use the `dict()` constructor on those; it is entirely redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the dict locally, update it with your extra info before returning:

```
def to_dict(self):
     retval = {'identification': self.identifier,
               'information': self.information,
              }
     if self.children:
         retval['nodes'] = {e.position: e.to_dict for e in self.children}
     return retval
```

I removed the `dict()` constructor in my example, it is entirely redundant. But because all your keys are also valid python identifiers, you *could* define your dict in a slightly more compact manner by using the `dict()` constructor and keyword arguments:

```
def to_dict(self):
     retval = dict(identification=self.identifier,
                   information=self.information)
     if self.children:
         retval['nodes'] = {e.position: e.to_dict for e in self.children}
     return retval
```

Comment: Simple, clear solution. If you had a lot of potential if statements, you could store them in another dictionary and then do ``retval.extend({key: value for key, value in potentials.items() if value})``.